# C how to access a struct member in a struct?

Tags: c

I have a struct that has a struct as a member, and I want to access that member from the first struct. You didn't get it? I will show you.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int day;
} Date;

typedef struct 
{
    struct Date;
} Insert;

Insert insert;

scanf("%d", &insert.day); // I tried this but it doesn't work
scanf("%d", &insert.date.day); // Figured maybe this would do it, but nope
```

Comment: I also tried &insert.Date.day but that gave me the error `error: invalid use of 'struct Training::Date'`. @Eric I have no idea about what you're asking. I don't understand.

Comment: regarding _scanf("%d", &insert.date.day); // I tried this but it doesn't work_  There is no where in your code that has _date_.  Only _Date_.  See answer below for details.

Comment: Unless you are using a rather old compiler, don't use typedef with structs anymore *(it was proper once, but is now outdated)*.  Instead:  `struct Date { int day; };`

Answer (score 0):

You need :

```
typedef struct 
{
    Date date;
} Insert;

Insert insert;
```

Then,

```
scanf("%d", &insert.date.day);
```

Comment: Ah, but that gives me the error: `using typedef-name 'Date' after 'struct'` and `'Date' has a previous declaration here`

Comment: DAYYYYYYYM. I typed `struct Date date;`. I should have left `struct` out! Damn!

Answer (score 0):

***As others have said***, the way you have your code written, it will not build.  You *should* get an error where indicated in the following:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int day;
} Date;

typedef struct 
{
    struct Date;//Error here - Undefined size for field, incomplete struct Date defined at cfile.c:8
} Insert;

Insert insert;

int main(void)
{
    return 0;   
}
```

***You have already created*** a type `Date` (i.e. `typedef struct`...`Date`), use it instead of `struct Date;` like this:  ***(this will build)***

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
typedef struct 
{
    int day;
} Date;//you have just created a new type:  struct Date here..., use "Date date;" below, (not struct Date;)

typedef struct 
{
    Date date;//"Date is a type (typedef struct Date), so use it here to declare the member "date"
} Insert;

Insert insert;

int main(void)
{
    return 0;   
}  

int main(void)
{
      scanf("%d", &insert.date.day);
      return 0; 
}
```